# Python PEP-8: Assignment following E122 and E501

Tags: python, pep

How should I improve the assignment of many or long variables to follow the rules E122 and E501 in a case as the following:

```
def my_example_function():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4
# How can I improve the following line:
first_variable, second_variable, third_variable, fourth_variable = my_example_function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just span it over multiple lines..

```
( first_variable, second_variable, 
  third_variable, fourth_variable ) = my_example_function()
```

Comment: That was a rather easy answer. I like it especially because I my variables are already about 80 characters long. But I do not know why I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

[E122 says the line should be less than 80 characters, and E501 says that continuation lines should be indented.](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html)  A common way of rewriting that line would be,

```
first_variable, second_variable, third_variable, fourth_variable = \   
    my_example_function()
```

Comment: This is a common way in C and other languages, but _not_ encouraged in Python. Unless there are obvious reasons, avoid that if you can and use braces.